# Error when exporting "MXDPERFSTAT" tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, performance, mxd

I am running this tool: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a269d03aa1c840638680e2902dadecac Mxdperfstat- basically it records the loading time for drawing the layers so you can optimize data and map docs before publishing them.

Everything seems to work fine but my output file is just a .txt with a bunch of source code which means nothing to me (I can't understand). I tried to open it by double clicking and it opens with notepad Like this img:
[image]

and when I right click and open with a web browser it just opens an empty page nothing is displayed (all white).

The results I am expecting are referred to this page:
http://egis3.lacounty.gov/eGIS/2012/02/21/tune-your-map-data-before-publishing-mxdperfstat/

[image]

Anyone have any ideas why my output is coming out like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually an XML file not a text file per say. Open it with Internet Explorer (Shutters) I know but it actually works for this. Note, oddly Edge does not...